# TypeError: must be str, not type for user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

The script is supposed to ask the user to define a variable and then print what they typed, also telling him the variable's type.

```
xtyped = input("Give me something :\n")
print("You typed :" + xtyped + " and its type is " + type(xtyped))
```

It throws an error:

> TypeError: must be str, not type

Comment: I don't think we should mark it as a duplicate to an old method of string formatting

Comment: 1. `input()` will always return str.

Comment: 2. You misused the quotations.

Comment: @sshashank124 If we stop using questions with a bad accepted answer as duplicates just because people can't scroll down a little, we'll need *a lot* of new canonicals. Downvote the outdated answer, upvote the one below it, and move on. Or find a better dupe.

Comment: @sshashank124 Wow, you actually reopened this obvious dupe that gets asked 3 times a week? Surely there's a duplicate target that you agree with somewhere?

Comment: @Aran-Fey That was not my only reason for reopening it. This question has other points for discussion such as the fact that `input` always returns `str` and the fact that `type` returns `type` not `str`. You can link back the dupe

Comment: Well, I only get one close vote. Here you go though: Duplicate of [Identifying the data type of an input](//stackoverflow.com/q/22199741) and [How do I put a variable inside a String in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2960772) or [How can I print variable and string on same line in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/17153779)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the type of `input` is always `str`
But here when you want to do string concatenation it is unable to concatenate as `type(xtyped)` is a `type` object not `str`.

So, You need to convert to `str` of `type(xtyped)` using `str()`

```
xtyped = input("Give me something :\n")
print("You typed : " + xtyped + " and its type is "+ str(type(xtyped)))
```

Output:

```
  Give me something :
  hello
  You typed : hello and its type is <class 'str'>
```

Comment: Or you can also use `format()`: `'Type: {}'.format(type(xtyped))`

Comment: @Τάκης Κανάβ: This will resolve your error

Comment: `input()` always returns str though...

Comment: @takiskan: Did you solved the issue ?

Comment: @kvmahesh i did and it works thanks !